# Using Vega how can you toggle more complex conditions using a signal?

Tags: javascript, visualization, vega-lite, vega

I am creating a visualization with three categories that the points fit in to, represented by a color scale. What I would like to have is a checkbox that when checked enables the color scale and when unchecked results in all points being the same color. I have got this working with single color names, but I do not know how to change one condition so its either the single color or scale. Here is my code.

```
signals: [
    {
        name: "toggleColor",
        value: true,
        bind: {input: "checkbox"}
    }
]
...
marks: [
        {
            type: "symbol",
            from: {data: "surveys"},
            encode: {
                update: {
                    x: {field: "survey_answer", scale: "xScale"},
                    y: { field: "survey_item", scale: "yScale"},
                    fill: {
                        //This is where I want the signal to go
                        //signal: "toggleColor ? 'green' : 'red'"
                        //But instead one side should enable the scale

                        field: "class",
                        scale: "colorScale"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Please provide a full working spec and desired output

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"fill": {"signal": "toggleColor ? scale('colorScale', datum.class) : 'grey'"}
```